# what's the purpose of adding ngModel attribute alone with no value?

Tags: html, angular

I was watching this angular tutorial video and I'm still confused about why he used ngModel attribute alone without a value and the purpose of the template variable #firstName in respect to the syntax he's using.
What exactly happens when using this syntax?

[this is the youtube video](https://youtu.be/hAaoPOx_oIw?t=990)

component.html

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input required ngModel name="firstName" #firstName="ngModel" class="form-control" (change)="log(firstName)">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comment">Comment</label>
        <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we use a template reference variable, Angular understand in general that the "variable" is type of the component if the template reference variable is related in a component or an ElementRef or a htmlElement if it is in a html tag.

If our html tag has a directive, Angular understand in general that is type of the directive else some elements as `input`, so you use the way (*)

```
#myVariable="directive"
```

Now, you can use in the html the template reference variable (in .ts you get it using [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)) with all the properties of the "directive". so, in your example you can use,e.g.

```
{{firstName.valid}}
```

Brief:

1. You say that your input is "special", it's not only an input else
   has the properties of ngModel
2. Your template reference variable can use the properties/methods of
   the directive

(*) really is not the directive else the name we use in [exportAs](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#exportas) of the directive

Comment: Thank you, this helped me understand it. One quick question, does this mean that the scope of the variable #myVariable expands to the entire Html document?

Comment: It's a variable of the **component**, so you can use in all the component.html, and, using `@ViewChild` in the .ts of the component. Be careful, if the tag is under a `*ngIf="false"` you not has the variable -in this case you can use `[style.display]="none"` instead *ngIf-